# DataGrid refresh after cell edit

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I've seen many similar questions regarding the DataGrid, but nothing that directly addresses my situation.

I need to manually refresh my DataGrid after a cell has been edited.  The problem is that I cannot figure out when a cell is finished editing.  The DataGrid only has a CellEditEnding event (though in SilverLight they provide a CellEditEnded).  Calling `Refresh()` on my collection view while in CellEditEnding throws an error saying that it's not allowed while a cell is being edited.

I need to refresh the entire grid because values in other rows may depend upon the value that was edited.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView then there is a "CellEndEdit" event or a "CellLeave" or a "CellValueChange" events.

If not please do specify exacly what control you are refering to... WinForm or asp...

Comment: `DataGrid`s exist in `WPF`. The post is tagged with `WPF` too.